# Android widget on every ImageView click instantiates new object

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm brand new to developing widgets for android so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.  I'm writing my own mp3 player specific to my needs.  I have it working great as an app, but now I'd like to pull it out into a homescreen widget as well (more for the learning exercise than anything else).

I split out my mp3 player logic into a separate class, and when I try and intantiate an object from that class with a button click from my widget, it works fine.  The problem is, I can't seem to use that same object for the next time that button is clicked or any other button for that matter.  Instead, it recreates a new object each time a button is clicked inside my widget.  I'm just trying to make my play/pause ImageView function properly.

Here is the code for my WidgetProvider

```
package com.example.musicplayerforburrito;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String WIDGET_PLAY_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.PLAY_PAUSE_WIDGETS";
    MusicPlayerClass mpc = new MusicPlayerClass();

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {


      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
      ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playpausewidget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, WIDGET_PLAY_BUTTON));
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onReceive(context, intent);
      AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout );
      ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
      if (WIDGET_PLAY_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {

          if(!mpc.hasFolders)
              mpc.Initialize();
          if(!mpc.isPlaying)
          {
              remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.mp3filename, mpc.StartSong());
              remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpausewidget, R.drawable.pause); 
          }
          else
          {
              mpc.PauseMusic();
              remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpausewidget, R.drawable.play); 
          }
          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);     
      }      
  }

  protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
      intent.setAction(action);
      return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
  }
}
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an object to be associated with the class instead of having one for each instance you need to declare it as `static`.  That means that each time your create an instance of the containing class they will all reference the same object.

Comment: so are you suggesting I change the mpc object (instance of MusicPlayerClass) to static?

Comment: Yes, that should allow all instances of your `MyWidgetProvider` to access the same instance of it.